# Consider the probability space Ω = {0, 1}^ 3 with equally likely outcomes.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Show that there are 70 different Bernoulli random variables of parameter 1/2 that can be defined on Ω.

Answer (score 1):

Since each of the outcomes is equally likely, Bernoulli random variables of parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ correspond to subsets of $\Omega$ of size $4$ ($|\Omega| = 8$). There are $\binom{8}{4} = 70$ such subsets, so there are $70$ such Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: so if the parameter was 1/3 instead, would there be 8C3 Bernoulli Random Variables?

Comment: Parameter $1/3$ is impossible, since there are $8$ possible outcomes. $\frac{n}{8} \neq \frac{1}{3}$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: I'm still confused, what does it mean for a bernoulli rv to have paramter 1/2 and why do they correspond to the subsets of Ω ?

Comment: @GreatP Bernoulli RVs can take on one of two possible values (let's call them $a$ and $b$). One of these values corresponds to a "success" (say, $a$), and the other to "failure" (say, $b$). The Bernoulli RV of parameter $p$ takes on value $a$ with probability $p$ and value $b$ with probability $1-p$. If you are looking at a Bernoulli RV with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$, then the set of outcomes that you consider "success" must be the same size as the one you consider "failure", since all outcomes have equal probability here. That's why they correspond to subsets of $\Omega$ of size $4$.